# WSUS Post-Installation Tasks Failed Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I am installing WSUS on a server running Server 2012. The post-installation tasks fail. I have tried un-installing, then re-installing WSUS with no luck.

This is the error message in the logs :

> Instantiating UpdateServer
>
> CreateDefaultSubscription Failed: Exception: System.InvalidOperationexception: client found response content type of 'text/html charset=utf-8' but expected 'text/xml'

I'm not sure what this error means. I researched it and I haven't found any other suggestion besides re-installing WSUS again. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: It seems like an issue with IIS - open it and check if your WSUS is running okay there. If yes, check SQL/WID

Answer (score 1):

-Open IIS console -> Sites -> Delete "WSUS Administration"site then open the WSUS console or reinitialize the post installation again; this should work